# Xamarin Forms ViewModel with List in List

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I created a ViewModel that does a webcall and collects a List with albums: List.

Here is the Album class:

```
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Image> Image { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see the Album contains another List with Images:

```
public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
}
```

In the xaml I created a CollectionView that does get filled with the Albums, but in the Albums I want to show all the images the album contains.
The problem is that I don't know how to show those images from the `albumList<Album>`. Here is my current xaml:

```
<CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid HeightRequest="86">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                        Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                        Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='€ {0:F2}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18"/>
            </StackLayout>

            <!--
            Show all the images -->

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is an example image of the result I want:
[image]

How can I create this layout?

### UPDATE

To get one bigger image I removed the first image from the list and created a Image in a different grid column. But that doesn't get displayed. Here is the xaml I have now:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding albumList}">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HeightRequest="86">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="3"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" 
                        Aspect="AspectFill">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <FileImageSource File="{Binding demoImage}" />
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="18" />
                    <Label VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding Price, StringFormat='€ {0:F2}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="18"/>
                </StackLayout>



                <StackLayout  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="3" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="55" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>




            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

demoImage is a different variable ImageSource in the ViewModel, but the demoImage doesn't get displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/grouping

Comment: Thanks, but in that example it will create foreach image in my album a new row, but I want 1 row for the album, within that row every image displayed

Comment: then use a horizontal layout instead.

Comment: As @Jason 's comment and @Lucas' s answer describes horizontal orientation StackLayout is all you need. Do you set the image in the left most column from the Album list? Then a `SelectedImageSource` property to the Album model could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **Bindable Layouts** . Which enable any layout class that derives from the Layout class to generate its content by binding to a collection of items.

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout  Grid.Row="xx" Grid.Column="xx" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Image}" Orientation="Horizontal">
   <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>

          <Image  HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFit" Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>

      </DataTemplate>
   </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

#### in code behind

```
public class MyImage
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string MyImageSource { get; set; }
}
```

Note: I noticed that you define your iamge class as **Image** , which maybe will have name conflict with Xamarin.Forms.Image . So you would better rename it like `MyImage`

#### Update

```
<Image  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="2" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding demoImage}" />
```

```
public class Album
    {

        public Album()
        {
            DemoImage = Images[0].MyImageSource;
            Images.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MyImage> Images { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }

        public string DemoImage { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked.... Still 1 question about this, for achieving what I want as result. I want the first image of the `List<MyImage>`  to be large and in a different place in the `Grid` like on my example image. Then all the other images need to be displayed like your code, except of course for the first one. How can I do that?

Comment: Put the image in the specific cell of grid, then set the binding .

Comment: Can you please tell me how to set the binding for 1 image and how I can skip the fist image for the BindingLayout?

Comment: You could remove the first source from the list,and set it as the source of the specific Image...

Comment: You could share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206919/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-a-vreeswijk).